# Save or insert entire listview data into sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview

Does anyone know how to save the entire listview data into sqlite?

I have a list of data from database and I would like to update all of the data into sqlite.

Comment: If you are talking about update query this is the syntax.

    UPDATE table_name
    SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
    WHERE some_column=some_value;

Comment: Nope, actually I'm looking the portion of code to save all the data from the listview to sqlite. Most of the example are just storing single row of data from listview.

Answer (score 0):

you can update data in for loop till the size of listview

Comment: I using array adapter to display my data into listview, what i want is to store my array adapter into sqlite.